# PHP prepared statement not returning array

Tags: php

My array is empty when I'm binding an id variable. The table contains 5 columns that I'd like in an array. This is what I tried:

```
$records = array();
$id = 22;

if($results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = ?")) {
$results->bind_param('i', $id);
$results->execute();
if($results->num_rows) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $records[] = $row;
    }
    $results->free();
}
}

print_r($records);
```

Comment: Why do not `fetchAll`?

Comment: thanks!  can you give me an example, please.

Comment: `$records = $results->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` after execute before print_R

Comment: `if($results->num_rows) {` is redundant here. As well as `$results->free();`

Answer (score 0):

you are binding param 'i' but using a '?' placeholder. Use one of these:

```
if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = ?")) {
$results->bind_param(1, $id);
```

or

```
if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = :i")) {
$results->bind_param(':i', $id);
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php for more examples.

Comment: You need to pay more attention to the code you are commenting

Comment: I think OP was edited, tweaking code now. If you see something please be specific? thx.

Comment: and yes, fetch_object() in a loop shows a weak understanding of PDO patterns, but it's also instructive to look at why the code as written is failing.

Comment: It is not his fault but entirely yours

Comment: If I have made a mistake please by all means point it out. I will endeavor to fix it. If you are just saying "you need to pay more attention" you are implying there's something wrong without being helpful.

Comment: To pay more attention to the question is the only way to fix your answer. I am not supposed to be "helpful" though, no matter what meaning you put in. However, I am, while your idea on the helpfulness is somewhat narrow.

Comment: OP's code looks like mysqli to me, not PDO. (bind_param vs. bindParam, ? as a placeholder)